# Android ListView not displaying more than 8 digits

Tags: java, android, database, listview

I'm storing miliseconds from alarms to database and database has them all stored correctly since I test it displaying them in a single TextView and it displays them all. But my ListView only displays miliseconds value which has 8 numbers, when there are 9 number or more it doesn't display them. Here is my ListView :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

My xml I use for rows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"        
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="45dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Method that I use for populating the ListView :

```
private void fillData() {
        // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
        Cursor c = DatabaseManager.getAllData();
        startManagingCursor(c);

        String[] from = new String[] { DatabaseManager.TABLE_COLUMN_TWO };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };

        // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
        SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, c, from, to);
        setListAdapter(notes);
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't display them or it only displays 8 digits from 9 or more?

Comment: @Simon It displays 8 digits or less, 9 or more don't get displayed at all, the whole number (row) doesn't get displayed if its 9 or more digits. Like it doesn't exist at all (but it is in the database)

Comment: @Simon So if its a number with 8 or less digits it gets displayed in its row in ListView but if its a number with 9 digits, it doesn't get populated in the ListView.

Comment: That's very strange.  I would try writing my own adapter and testing.  http://blog.cluepusher.dk/2009/11/16/creating-a-custom-cursoradapter-for-android/

Answer (score 0):

```
Please replace the Listview with following code. 
Its working good.
Don't fix the height of the Listview in android:layout_height
Please replace your layout xml code with the following xml.
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you for suggestion but it doesn't work. try and test it on a 3.2 inch (320x480) screen you will see it doesn't work. it works on larger screens but on smaller doesn't.

Comment: i tested it in different devices. Its working fine. what version are you using and can you plz attach screen shot. are you testing in emulator or mobile devices?